# I have a solenoid rated at 24 volts AC, but at a trickle voltage of 1-9 volts the solenoid stays pulled in when it shouldn't be

Tags: voltage, zener, coil, solenoid, low-voltage

I have a solenoid that pulls in at 24-30 volts ac to control water flow. It opens at 24 volts ac, but stays pulled in at a trickle voltage of .75 -1.0 volts. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you include the model # for the solenoid and additional information (ideally a schematic) on the system or circuitry controlling it? You included a tag for Zener, how is that related?

Comment: Is your trickle voltage AC or DC? A solenoid generally needs a lower operating voltage on DC than AC due to the lack of inductive reactance.

Answer (score 2):

0.75V to 1.0V seems like an extremely low holding voltage for a 24V solenoid. I suspect the flow of water is contributing appreciably to the holding voltage. Consider operating the solenoid without the water - I bet it drops out around 8V-14V. I suspect the flow direction is wrong and water flow is helping with keeping the solenoid open - change the flow direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [pull-in current](https://industrial-electronics.com/output_devices_amplifiers_valves_relays_variable-frequency_drives_stepper_motors_servomotors/Pull-In_Hold-In_Current.html) for a solenoid is, by its nature, always greater than the holding current. In an extreme case, a *D.C.* solenoid made from a "hard" alloy can stay pulled in with *no* current flowing.

What can you do?

- Get rid of that 0.75 - 1.0 volt. Try two (or four) ordinary silicon diodes (e.g., 1N4007), *back-to-back* (i.e., in parallel but pointing opposite directions... antiparllel, as R. McMahon states) in series with the solenoid coil. Why waste standby current, anyway? See [Trevor's Repair Cafe](https://therepaircafe.wordpress.com/2019/10/24/forward-voltage-of-various-diodes/) for a chart of forward voltage drop vs. current for a variety of semiconductors.
- Mechanically arrange the solenoid so that it never completely is pulled in -- leave a mm or so space between plunger and metal bottom. This might be as simple as adjusting its mounting, or inserting a small, *non-magnetic* spacer in the bore.
- Increase the strength of the solenoid's spring.

Comment: The solenoid is AC operated. While one of more series diodes MAY achieve what he wants I don't think that that's what you meant to suggest.  To use just diode voltage drop (and not half wave rectification) he'd need one or more pairs of anti-parallel diodes.  (You know that :-) ) || Or series opposed zeners.

Answer (score 1):

Many solenoid valves only work properly with one orientation (water in/out), due to pressure and forces on the internal valves surfaces.  Worth checking you've connected the water the right way round (and that it is in the rated pressure range).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that residual voltage with a 24 VAC relay, with a SPDT contact. When no power is sent to solenoid, you can short the coil with the normally closed contact.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFVY4P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>